Trying to confirm what version my thinkstation will run
First time user and I want to see what version of Ubuntu my system will run.
I looked on the certified page and did not see my think station listed.
It is a Lenovo Thinkstation P510 with
32 GB ram,
The processor is a Xeon E-5 2697 v3 and the video card is a
Nvida Quadro K2200.
I don't want to go through the struggle of trying to install if I am going to be as outdated as this no longer supported version of Windows 11 is.
I am so sorry if this was already asked somewhere.  I spent about 1/2 an hour trying to find the answer and did not see a clear direction.
Many Thanks!

It is always wise to install the latest available version, which is Ubuntu 24.04  LTS currently. This is especially important for newer hardware. Every other suggestion will be opinion based, which is not something done here in AskUbuntu.

Thanks, and I agree - but if the hardware wouldn't support the latest version then I may run into issues.

Will this help? https://askubuntu.com/questions/986878/will-my-device-work-with-ubuntu

Just try it in a live session.

This question is similar to: How do I find out which version and derivative of Ubuntu is right for my hardware in terms of minimal system requirements?. If you believe it’s different, please edit the question, make it clear how it’s different and/or how the answers on that question are not helpful for your problem.
